# Casting screen from Android mobile to Android Tablet

Tags: android

I need to develop 2 applications "Sender" and "Receiver". These two will perform screen mirroring from Sender to Receiver.

How can I do this? Are there any in-built APIs / libraries available for same? 
Can I use Miracast to achiave this? If, yes please guide me.

Assumption: Both device will be remain on same wifi.

Comment: "Are there any in-built APIs / libraries available for same?" -- no. "Can I use Miracast to achiave this?" -- no. Beyond that, you need to provide **much** more information about what your "Sender" app is trying to send. It it trying to send its own UI? Is it trying to send anything that is on the screen, including the content of other applications?

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks for your input. "Sender" will mirror its own UI i.e. content on its own screen these can be docs and images. I do not need to access content of other apps.

Answer (score 0):

To collect the UI from Sender, you can try creating something that looks like my `MirroringFrameLayout` from [the CWAC-Layouts library](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-layouts). That is designed to update a separate `Mirror` `View` for on the same device that has the `MirroringFrameLayout`, such as having the `MirroringFrameLayout` on the touchscreen and the `Mirror` shown on an external display via a `Presentation`.

The problem you will encounter is performance, as my current approach draws the entire `MirrorFrameLayout` contents to a `Bitmap`, which is then shown by the `Mirror`. That would require you to ship new bitmaps across the network connection on every UI change, which is likely to be slow. So, while my approach is easy, you may need to be much more aware of what your UI is doing so you can ship over smaller updates.

The best approach may be to stop thinking of "screen mirroring" entirely, and instead focus on "operation mirroring". For example, suppose Sender is a drawing app, and Receiver is supposed to see the drawings. Rather than sending over the screens, send over the drawing operations that the user performs, and apply those same operations on the Receiver.